# Marking the line(s) that has/have an error in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

Often it is useful to mark the lines where an error exists, in order to pinpoint [it] easily should you want to edit the code in the future.

How one can do such an action in Atom editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mark lines manually, you can use the built-in *Bookmarks* package, which provides actions for marking lines, going back to the bookmarked lines, and viewing all available bookmarks:

https://atom.io/packages/bookmarks

Comment: I press `cmd = windows key` and `F2`, but I cannot have the line marked. Instead a hear a characteristic Windows sound.

Comment: The key binding for Windows is different from the Mac. Check here for the Windows key bindings: https://github.com/atom/bookmarks/blob/master/keymaps/bookmarks.cson